# Need help identifying unicode characters

Tags: unicode

I am currently writing a tool for the game Keep Talking And Nobody Explode. The game have one of the puzzle revolving around symbol, and I've sucessfully identified a good part of them as unicode character.

However, I am at a loss for some of them, and reading throught the entire unicode charset is... quite time intensive.

Here are all the differents symbols:

[image: I have horrible Pinta skills]

And from up to down, left to right, the list of all thoses that I have identified:

```
| Name                                              | U+   | Char |
|---------------------------------------------------|------|------|
| GREEK LETTER ARCHAIC KOPPA                        | 03d8 | Ϙ    |
| CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER LITTLE YUS                | 0466 | Ѧ    |
| LATIN SMALL LETTER LAMBDA WITH STROKE             | 019b | ƛ    |
| ???                                               |      |      |
| CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IOTIFIED BIG YUS          | 046c | Ѭ    |
| ???                                               |      |      |
| GREEK CAPITAL REVERSED DOTTED LUNATE SIGMA SYMBOL | 03ff | Ͽ    |
| ???                                               |      |      |
| CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ABKHASIAN HA              | 04a8 | Ҩ    |
| WHITE STAR                                        | 2606 | ☆    |
| INVERTED QUESTION MARK                            | 00bf | ¿    |
| COPYRIGHT SIGN                                    | 00a9 | ©    |
| ???                                               |      |      |
| CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ZHE WITH DESCENDER        | 0496 | Җ    |
| ???                                               |      |      |
| ???                                               |      |      |
| PILCROW SIGN                                      | 00b6 | ¶    |
| LATIN SMALL LETTER B WITH STROKE                  | 0180 | ƀ    |
| ???                                               |      |      |
| GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PSI                          | 03c8 | ψ    |
| GREEK CAPITAL DOTTED LUNATE SIGMA SYMBOL          | 03fe | Ͼ    |
| CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER KSI                       | 046e | Ѯ    |
| BLACK STAR                                        | 2605 | ★    |
| CYRILLIC THOUSANDS SIGN                           | 0482 | ҂    |
| LATIN SMALL LETTER AE                             | 00e6 | æ    |
| ???                                               |      |      |
| GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA                        | 03a9 | Ω    |
```

For the 13th letter, it look a lot like ["CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER BROAD OMEGA"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a64c/index.htm) (Ꙍ), but with a modifier.

Can somebody help me pinpoint the rest of the list?

Comment: if they were in actual text I could tell you in 2 minutes, as a picture, nope :/

Comment: @Tetsujin I have the exact same problem, I ve searched for a clear-text version of the game's manual, but the only available versions are pdf-based, so image. If I had the text version, I would have searched for a tool to get the code from the character directly :/

Comment: I have (wrote) a tool if you have (had) the text.

Comment: Found some: ҊѼϗԆ

Comment: I can say that U+0180 is wrong though; there is no font where it looks like an inverted P. Ѣ is more likely. And switching to a serif font confirms it.

Comment: And ټбϞӬ should round it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [ShapeCatcher](https://shapecatcher.com) to find these:

Column 1, row 4: 0x3DE, GREEK LETTER KOPPA
Column 1, row 6: 0x3D7, GREEK KAI SYMBOL
Column 2, row 1: 0x4EC, CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER E WITH DIERESIS
Column 2, row 6: 0x47C, CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA WITH TITLO
Column 3, row 1: 0x506, CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER KOMI DZJE
Column 3, row 2: 0x3EC, COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER SHIMA
Column 3, row 5: 0x67C, ARABIC LETTER TEH WITH RING
Column 4, row 5: 0x48A, CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER SHORT I WITH TAIL

Comment: As far as the comment from @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that it's not 0x180, I agree; that one is most likely 0x462, CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER YAT, though it could also be 0x48C, CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER SEMISOFT SIGN.